# What is the best way to use ThreadLocal - through static or non-static methods?

Tags: java, thread-local

For my application, I have to carry certain information to each layer of the application (one example could be a unique transaction id generated for incoming request).

So, I am planning to create a class which has a reference to `ThreadLocal<ConcurrentMap<String, Object>>`.

Appreciate if someone can help; I have a confusion, out of following approach, which one is better:

**1. AppContext.java having static methods**

```
public final class AppContext {
  private static final ThreadLocal&lt;ConcurrentMap&lt;String, Object&gt;&gt; context = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public static void set(final String key, final Object value) {
    // set key value in thread local
  }

  public static Object get(final String key) {
    // get value from thread local
  }
}
```

**2. AppContext.java having non-static methods**

```
public final class AppContext {
  private static final ThreadLocal&lt;ConcurrentMap&lt;String, Object&gt;&gt; context = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public void set(final String key, final Object value) {
    // set key value in thread local
  }

  public Object get(final String key) {
    // get value from thread local
  }
}
```

Comment: It's up to you. It doesn't matter if the `ThreadLocal` is accessed statically or not.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `ConcurrentMap` (thread safe) with a `ThreadLocal` (provider of non thread safe objects)?

Comment: @Iae, I do not have a convincing answer for you honestly. Could you please elaborate if you see any issue with this?

Comment: This seems like a bad use of ThreadLocal. What happens if someone uses the AppContext from another thread?

Comment: @David, I am sorry if I did not understand your question. If your point is how to protect data from getting shared among threads (a typical scenario in web apps where threads are reused), sparty02's answer tells how to take care. In fact, one of my previous applications, we put a spring interceptor to make sure data from thread local is removed before response is written back. Anyways, my original question is still semi-answered in the sense I am still kind of confused which one is the correct approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite what others may say, ThreadLocal variables aren't inherently evil, they just require a little extra care and understanding when using.  Thread safety isn't really relevant as they are inherently tied to one thread.  The concern comes in when those threads may be reused by other, disparate users of an application.  In Java based web apps, this is the case; HOWEVER, you can count on only one user/request living on that thread at one time.  The extremely important step is to ensure you clean up your ThreadLocal objects at the end of each request.

Therefore, to avoid having to unnecessarily instantiate a new context for every request, I would recommend creating multiple static type-safe ThreadLocal objects, all living in a "context" class where these objects are related in some way.  You can use multiple context classes to organize various groups of these contextual items.

However, in the spirit of ThreadLocal critics, I would agree that ThreadLocals should be used somewhat sparingly and overuse can potentially be a code smell.

Following is an example of the aforementioned approach.

**The "context" class.**

```
public class LogContext {

    private static ThreadLocal<String> localCorrelationId = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    private static ThreadLocal<String> localUserId = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public static String getCorrelationId() {
        return localCorrelationId.get();
    }

    public static void setCorrelationId(String correlationId) {
        localCorrelationId.set(correlationId);
    }

    public static String getUserId() {
        return localUserId.get();
    }

    public static void setUserId(String userId) {
        localUserId.set(userId);
    }

    public static void cleanup() {
        localCorrelationId.remove();
        localUserId.remove();
    }
}
```

**Managing the context via a Servlet Filter**

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "LogContextFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class LogContextFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {
            LogContext.setCorrelationId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //This is critical!
            LogContext.cleanup();
        }

    }

    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

**Accessing the context (e.g. from a Servlet)**

```
@WebServlet(name = "SimpleServlet", urlPatterns = {"/SimpleServlet"})
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String correlationId = LogContext.getCorrelationId();
    }

}
```

Comment: I wish Java had split the `ThreadLocal` concept into two classes, one of which would behave as `ThreadLocal<T>` does, and one of which would have a `create` method that accepts an ID and an object, stores them in a linked list, and returns an `AutoCloseable`, and `get` method that would return the most recently created entry with that ID; closing the `AutoCloseable` returned by `create` would delete that entry *as well as any that were created after it*.  Thread-local variables are often needed for strictly-LIFO purposes, and having a class just for that...

Comment: ...would be cleaner and more performant than having to add and remove items from a hash table.

Comment: Similar approach is described here:
https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-correlation-ids-0

Answer (score 1):

If `AppContext` is a singleton, then static methods are the best way to go. If there is more than one `AppContext`, then you should have the methods be non-static.

Answer (score -1):

There is no best way to use ThreadLocal.  Think of it as "Global Variable" and everything negative that entails.  ThreadLocal is a pox upon the earth.  A cancer in your application that someday will grow to consume you.  Avoid it at all costs.  Learn how to pass proper immutable state and let your Threading woes just melt away.

Comment: Well, Bob I understand the threading woes, but think about this; I have to relate all my Classes/methods called for a transaction starting from user's request (servlet level) till the innermost layer (DAO layer may be!). And, to achieve something like this, its easier to carry a transaction id (which is generated at web layer) through a `ThreadLocal`. Can you suggest what could be a better solution for such use cases?

Comment: also functional languages like clojure, which use immutable state, make use of threadlocal state... by the way, if a variable is thread-local means it is thread safe :)

Comment: If you need a Transaction to transit across your layers create your own Transaction object, make it Threadsafe, and pass it around.  The advantages are numerous, not least of which is your DAOs and the like become testable, reusable outside of any particular framework, and refactoring becomes almost trivial.  I've lost hours to days in ThreadLocal hell and do not like to see others wallow away in their time.

Comment: @Niranjan, I was in a situation like yours, having to control the transaction of the dao layer which was filtered by an ever-committing facade (legacy code). We used a static method in order to set a static threadlocal connection - with no problems, as for now.

Comment: @Bob, AFAIK all container-manager persistence is handled by requiring that every transaction ends in a threadlocal context: you cannot share a same transaction in more threads.

Comment: @Niranjan Anyway, if possible, me too would avoid threadlocal: add a Connection parameter to all the layers's methods and let the final caller (may it be the web layer) handle the overall commit/rollback

Comment: @robermann, ThreadLocal != Thread-safe.  Its just an object that is local to a thread.  If you put some shared mutable state in that object that is being affected by other Threads, you will see race conditions.  I guess my point is that anything done with ThreadLocal can be done without it and with less side-effects or gotchas to be avoided.  In my experience, ThreadLocal is more risk than it is worth.

Comment: Hi All, I understand all these points and to be honest, this is the "only" thread local in our entire application (which is a REST service platform). We understand the multi threading issues and tried to discuss multiple solutions, but this one came out as a viable one for us. I cannot disclose all the design considerations, but trust me we tried to avoid this, but could not! Having said that, it seems I have to take care of few more things like (1) making AppContext singleton, (2) Try not to put shared mutable states into this and (3) remove all the data after the use. Right?